# PHP Intval() strange behaviour

Tags: php, wordpress, int

I am currently trying to resolve a problem with changing the type of a variable in order to be able to do math operations with it. I am trying to enhance a Wordpress plugin called "WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips".

There is a variable `$item['order_price']`, which contains a price with a currency sign. `var_dump()` of this variable returns `string(48)"709 Kč"`.
When I try to get the integer value using either `intval()` or casting it via `(int)`, it returns `0`.

What could be the solution?

Comment: `string(48)"709 Kč"` <- Do you see 48 characters here? Look into the source code and post the output from there

Comment: Odds are that it's wrapped in a <span>

Comment: I do not see 48 characters, but I really got this. Don't know how it's possible, also I don't see any span tags in source.

Comment: How do you get this value? Please add the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
filter_var($item['order_price'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use at least : trim($item['order_price']);